# How to define percentage height and width on a dotnet Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I tried this: http://dotnet.highcharts.com/Highcharts/Demo/Docs?section=FirstChart3

But there is no explanation for percentages.

I want to give my chart a height of 100% and a width of 100%. But I can't. And the surrounding div has a height and width of 100% and is working fine. But the Highchart is getting bigger then the div. That should be impossible and may not happen.

My code:

```
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    @(Html.Highsoft().Highcharts(
        new Highcharts
        {
            Chart = new Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Chart
            {
                PlotBackgroundColor = null,
                PlotBorderWidth = null,
                PlotShadow = null,
            },
            Title = new Title
            {
                Text = ""
            },
            Tooltip = new Tooltip
            {
                PointFormat = "{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>"
            },
            PlotOptions = new PlotOptions
            {
                Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
                {
                    AllowPointSelect = true,
                    Cursor = PlotOptionsPieCursor.Pointer,
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
                    {
                        Enabled = true,
                        Format = "<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %"
                    }
                }
            },
            Series = new List<Series>
            {
                new PieSeries
                {
                    Name = "Percentage",
                    Data = Model.SaleModel.WebshopPieData
                },

            }
        }
        , "webshopChart")
    )
</div>
```

**So please tell me what to do or where to look because I don't know anymore.
And please NO javascript examples. ONLY .NET code.**

Comment: Just out of curiosity can you try setting it to `100vw` for width and `100vh` for height?  Alternatively you can adjust the chart height and width within the options passed in to highcharts: `chart.height:  '100%', chart.width: '100%'`

Comment: No I can't do. The Width and Height of Chart are doubles. So a '%' or 'vw' or 'vh' will not be accepted.

Comment: Thie problem concerns double types and Highcharts developers work on it currently. Consistent solution for all cases of that kind should appear within next few days. I'll let you know as soon as I know anything.

Comment: Thanks Kamil! I am looking forward to hear from you.